# How to stop button being passed with parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I don't know why all of my form's buttons and submits keep passing the button in the Parameters also. An example would be If I use my search form and put in the word "Testing". The result I will get is below:

```
# Using Bootstrap 3.2.0 and Rails 4.1.1

 = form_tag products_path, method: :get do
  .input-group
    = text_field_tag :query, params[:query], class: 'form-control'
     %span.input-group-btn
      = button_tag(type: 'submit', class: 'btn') do
       Search

Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "query"=>"Testing", "button"=>""}
```

How can I make it not do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `name` attribute of `button` is `"button"` by default.

You could set it to nil by:

```
  = button_tag(type: 'submit', class: 'btn', name: nil) do
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this about HTML and how it worked.